# Template redefinition of default parameter compiles with g++ when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, templates, g++

The code below

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N = 10>
void f();

int main()
{
    f<>();
}

template <int N = 42>
void f()
{
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
}
```

re-defines a default template parameter. AFAIK, this should not be legal. clang++ indeed emits an error:

> error: template parameter redefines default argument

however g++ (4.9/5.1/6 HEAD) [compiles the code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/z14n0Krwup8NgsS8), it doesn't even emit a warning (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`). Am I missing something here or is this a g++ bug?

Comment: @yngum What do you mean never instantiated? The `f` below main provides the definition of the function, so I think it is instantiated. In fact the point of instantiation should be immediately after `main()`.

Comment: @yngum, My interpretation of this disagrees: *A template-parameter shall not be given default arguments by two different declarations in the same scope*. There's even an example there with just two lines: a forward declaration of class `X<T>`, and then a definition of it, that line being commented with "error".

Comment: oops, I thought `f` had a definition, look like a bug.